# PHP-AJAX CORS Fails due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cors, preflight

I am trying to make an AJAX call (CORS) using the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost/MySpace',
    success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
    },
    error: function() {
         console.log("error");
    },
});
```

I am running the above code from:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Test/index.html
```

The PHP Code written at `http://localhost/MySpace` is as below:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    echo "Hello";
?>
```

As per my understanding, this should have worked. However I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/MySpace. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What should I do make this work? Or am I doing something entirely wrong?

As per suggestions to debug the request I tried making a curl request:

```
curl -i http://127.0.0.1/MySpace/
```

And in response I can see that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is marked as `*`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 05:59:19 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.6.19 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As per the comment I added the below code to my `.htaccess`:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

@Edit:

This is my Response Header:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 09:26:44 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2g PHP/5.6.19 mod_perl/2.0.8- dev Perl/v5.16.3
Location: http://localhost/elasticservice/
Content-Length: 240
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

This is my request header:

```
POST /elasticservice HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
Origin: http://127.0.0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://127.0.0.1/test/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hi;q=0.6
```

Comment: Try .htaccess solution with access allow origin.

Comment: I tried adding .HTACCESS. But it is still not working. I have edited the question and have added the .HTACESS content

Comment: `<FilesMatch "\.(eot|ttf|otf|woff|xml|jpg|jpeg)$">
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
 </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>` i'm using this `.htaccess` code block to feed my cordova ios app. You can change file types or give permissions for all file types.

Answer (score 3):

You have allowed CORS Origin, so for access cross domain 3 headers `(Origin, Methods, Headers)` compulsory, see below sample headers

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

@update: you can try this solution

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            $headers=getallheaders();
            @$ACRH=$headers["Access-Control-Request-Headers"];
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: $ACRH");
        }

header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
```

Comment: did you change `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:` value from your api request headers?

Comment: api request headers? I only have three files: `.php` service of the AJAX, `.html` which is making AJAX call, `HTACCESS` as suggested in the comment.

Comment: I mean, check ajax request headers in browser console and add all into `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` they might be different.

Comment: I  tried the suggested change. It did not work either. I feel there is some problem with using `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`. But actually I am not able to use any URL on this. I have made an edit for my request and response header

Comment: You need add `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in the script which you are calling through AJAX not in htaccess

Answer (score 0):

try the following url:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/MySpace',
    success: function(result) {
         console.log(result);
    },
    error: function() {
         console.log("error");
    },
});
```

Comment: This will ovisly work. Because for localhost, it will not be considered as CORS.