# Problem with connecting a materila-kit based project to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Here's the console error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://...../android/appindex_platform.php' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)
```

this error happens when i want to fetch some data from the server

what is the problem?

Comment: Also as shown my server is php based

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP-AJAX CORS Fails due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204157/php-ajax-cors-fails-due-to-access-control-allow-origin)